# Require boolean attribute on model to be false or empty

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, webapi

How can I use annotations to require a boolean model property to be either `false` or empty?

Example:

```
// model
public class MyModel 
{
  public string StringProperty { get; set; }
  public bool BoolProperty { get; set; }
}
```

OK:

```
POST /someEndpoint
{
  "stringProperty": "foobar"
}

POST /someEndpoint
{
  "stringProperty": "foobar",
  "boolProperty": false
}
```

400:

```
POST /someEndpoint
{
  "stringProperty": "foobar",
  "boolProperty": true
}
```

I want to validate the model using `ModelState.IsValid`. So far, I've tried using `[Range(typeof(bool), "false", "false")]` but `ModelState.IsValid` returns true even if `boolProperty` is set to true. Any help?

Comment: Because it's not nullable, if it's omitted, it will be `false`. Why is that property part of the request model at all if it can only be `false`?

Comment: There's separate process that can generate these objects directly into storage. Only that backend process is allowed to set the value to `true`. API may retrieve items from the store that have this property set to `true`, but user created objects are not allowed to set it to `true`

Comment: Those should be entirely separate models, input vs. output. Input can't make that property anything but `false` so it shouldn't have the property.

Answer (score 1):

I created a custom validation attribute and it works for me

```
    public class AllowedOnlyFalse : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            if (value == null) return true;
            bool val = Convert.ToBoolean(value);
            return !val;
        }
    }

    // model
    public class MyModel
    {
        public string StringProperty { get; set; }

        [AllowedOnlyFalse]
        public bool BoolProperty { get; set; }
    }
```